# Jquery Animate not functioning like I expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a Table that periodically I need to update some data in it so I have the following code:

```
$.post('/Orders/Updated', function (data) {
for (var i in data.updatedOrders) {
    //alert(data.updatedOrders[i].Key);
    var orderV = $("div.vsi[data-key='" + data.updatedOrders[i].Key + "']");
    orderV.attr("data-r", data.updatedOrders[i].r);
    orderV.attr("data-v", data.updatedOrders[i].s);
    orderV.parent().animate({ backgroundColor: '#FFF' }, 300, "swing", function () {
        var icon = orderV.find("i");
        icon.removeClass();
        if (data.updatedOrders[i].Score <= 2) {
            icon.addClass("icon-ok-sign");
            icon.css("color", "#16fe03");
        } else if (data.updatedOrders[i].Score <= 13) {
            icon.addClass("icon-exclamation-sign");
            icon.css("color", "orange");
        } else {
            icon.addClass("icon-remove-sign");
            icon.css("color", "red");
        }
        $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }, 550);
    });
 }
}
```

The above code works fine and highlights the first update but then it updates the rest of the orders and does not highlight them. I've tried `queue: false` and `queue: "global"` based on other answers that I found with no luck. Any Ideas?

By the way the way I was doing the queue was like below

```
        .
        .
        .
        }
        $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }, 550);
    }, {queue: "global"});
```

**Update:** HTML Block:

```
<th class="to_hide_phone span1 " style="text-align: center; background-color: transparent;">
    <div class="vsi" data-r=" sample reason" data-v="0" data-key="somekey" data-original-title="" title="">
        <i class="icon-ok-sign" style="color: rgb(22, 254, 3); font-size: xx-large; margin-right: 5px;"></i>
    </div>
</th>
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML block that's in question?

Comment: @NeoNexusDeMortis Just added it :)

Comment: How is the JS block being called? I assume it's in a function you call upon table update?

Comment: yes, Success function of the jquery ajax

Comment: Can you provide it please? It's hard to tell what could be going wrong with the little that's here, as it seems to be fine. I need to see the order in which operations are being performed, mainly DOM manipulation.

Comment: its quite complicated. If I want to show that I would have to include the whole server side and everything else that happens before this and quite frankly im under an NDA so, I'm not even sure I can. But I can confirm that this is the only section that messes with animating the background color

Comment: funny thing is that it does iterate through all the orders and update them.

Comment: I don't need any real data, it can all be mocked up, and I don't need server-side code, I just need client-side as that's where the issue lies. Without more information, there is nothing I can do to help.

Comment: @NeoNexusDeMortis Sorry about that, and Thank you so much for trying to help me out with this one. I've included the post as it runs on document.ready is that what you needed?